# What does "economic drive" mean here?

Tags: vocabulary

> These systems are not typically designed to protect individual privacy, but since these services are typically free there is a **strong economic drive** for the service providers to harvest at least some information about their user's activities on the site in order to sell that information to advertisers for directed marketing.

<sup>Source: [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: Information Technology and Moral Values](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/it-moral-values/)</sup>

..........

Although I have studied the following definitions, I am wondering if the following definitions related to the bold part, and I cannot yet get what is the concept of the bold part yet.

Macmillan: [economy drive](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/economy-drive)

Cambridge Business English Dictionary: [economy drive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/economy-drive)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the phrase "economy drive" but "economic" &  "drive" - two separate words.

**[drive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive)** here is the impulse or motivation to do something and

**[economic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/economic)** as adjective describing *drive*, here based on economy.

So a **strong economic drive** is an impulse to do something due to economic reasons. Or very plainly in this context: These companies do something because they make money with it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The "economic drive" is a financial incentive, a monetary motivator.